# Append Number to a Name (string)

Tags: c#, regex, string

I want to append a Number to a name. The Result should look like `name-1` , `name-2`, `name-3`, etc

The problem is that name could be already have a dash and number at the number. In that case I  want the number to be incremented and not another number to be appended. This is used for a copy function.

Another problem is that the name could contain a dash so i can't use string.split
is there a clever way to do this. Maybe with regex ?

```
private string generateName(string name, int count) 
{ 
    string.Format("{0}-{1}",name,count);
}
```

Example:
Input => Ouput

name => name-1

name-1 => name-2

name-AB => name-AB-1

Comment: You are probably looking at a `Regex` solution that matches on string ending with a number preceded by a `-`

Comment: Or just a couple of if statements...

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed some example inputs, and the output you are expecting.

Comment: Added some example input/outputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(name, @"^(.*)-([0-9]+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (match.Success)
{
        return string.Format("{0}-{1}",match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value+ 1);
} else {
        return string.Format("{0}-{1}",name,count);
    }
```

Comment: A good way to lower the code count (if you like less code) is to get rid of oldnum and just do
    string.Format("{0}-{1}", name, match.Groups[1].Value + 1);

Comment: you will have a compile time error it you try to compile this, you are returning Value into string!

Comment: You also mixed some of your variables up.  You're using `input` in your call to `Regex.Match`, but `name` in your `string.Format` calls.

Comment: In addition, you are appending the incremented count to the end, rather than replacing the previous count with it.  For example, when given `name-1`, your code produces `name-1-2`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use regex (someone has posted a lovely answer) you could use this:

```
private string generateName(string name, int count) 
{ 
    // Find last dash
    int dashPos = name.LastIndexOf("-");
    if (dashPos == 0) return string.Format("{0}-{1}",name,count);

    // Extract content after last dash
    string lastEl = name.SubString(dashPos+1);
    int lastNumber;

    // Check if it is a number
    bool isNumber = int32.TryParse(lastEl, out lastNumber)
    if (isNumber){
        return string.Format("{0}-{1}", name.SubString(0, dashPos), ++lastNumber);
    }

    return string.Format("{0}-{1}", name, count);
}
```

Comment: Or use Niels' solution

Comment: You need to use the prefix-increment operator in order for your solution to work.  Currently, `lastNumber++` first retrives `lastNumber` and uses it in the `string.Format` call.  Then it increments `lastNumber`.  Because of this, any case where name ends with a number will result in the same number being returned.  For example, when given "name-1", your solution produces "name-1".

Comment: Cheers Jon, fixed. I had not come across the _pre_fix increment operator ++lastNumber. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply because you said it couldn't be done with `string.Split`...

You can use the split method.  If your name does not contain a '-', then split will return an array with a single string.  If the resulting array contains more than one string, all you have to do is check if the last one is a number.

```
private string generateName(string name) 
{ 
    var parts = name.Split('-');
    int lastPart = parts.Length - 1;
    // If we have more than one part, then we have a '-' in our name
    if(lastPart > 0)
    {
        int count;
        // If the last "part" is a number, just increment it
        if(int.TryParse(parts[lastPart], out count))
        {
            count++;    // increment counter
            parts[lastPart] = count.ToString();
            return string.Join("-", parts);
        }
    }
    // If we got here, then our string didn't end with a "-" followed by a number;
    // just append "-1" to the end.
    return name + "-1";
}
```

Using your example values, this produces the correct output.  In addition, this also handles the case where you have multiple numbers at the end:

```
╔══════════╦═══════════╗
║ Input    ║ Output    ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╣
║ name     ║ name-1    ║
║ name-1   ║ name-2    ║
║ name-AB  ║ name-AB-1 ║
║ name-1-2 ║ name-1-3  ║
╚══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

a very simple way to do it

```
 string d = "asd-a-151532";
    int i = d.LastIndexOf('-');
    string t = d.Substring(i + 1, d.Length - i - 1);
    var n = int.Parse(t) + 1;
    d = d.Substring(0, i + 1) + n.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine(t);
    Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Comment: Your solution does not account for the cases where either name does not contain a dash, or it ends with a dash, followed by a non-number.  In both cases, it will throw an exception (the first, due to `i` being an invalid index : -1; the second, due to `t` not being an integer).  Also, you should use more descriptive variable names to make your code easier to follow.

Comment: those cases have never been mentioned in the question, if so I would have wrote some extra code to handle such a cases also I am providing a solution for the problem not a copy-paste code, its a very simple problem with a very simple solution so no need for extra writing, if there is something not obvious enough I will provide extra explanation, thanks

Comment: Both of those cases are actually explicitly listed in the question.  The first case (no dash) is part of the question itself.  The second case (dash with non-number) is one of the example inputs listed.

Answer (score 0):

this pattern should work :

```
@"(\w+(-([^-0-9])+)*)"
```

the first value will be the name, the second value, if any the number.
It should work to a point with multiple '-' characters. it does nothing with empty characters.